# Why can't var be used in global scope?

Tags: c#, scope, var

I was just wondering why C# allows me to declare a variable using the `var` keyword inside a method

```
private SomeMethod()
{
    var someVariable = 5;
}
```

but not in global scope

```
Public partial class SomeClass
{
    var someVariable = 5;

    public SomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```

I've tried googling the question and I can't find any answers.

Comment: In your second example, `someVariable` is a `field`. How do you think compiler can decide it's type? From Eric Lippert; [Why no var on fields?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx)

Comment: Do you really can use it in method? Variables with var have to have defined type, so just var someVariable won't work. It have to be like this: var someVariable = 5;

Comment: @SonerGönül: Actually, both examples are illegal, but that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: [Right here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx)

Comment: @SLaks Yes, you are right of course without they didn't assign any value :)

Answer (score 1):

Field initializers can have cyclic dependencies.

How should the following code compile?

```
class A { public var a = B.b; }
class B { public var b = A.a; }
```

Local variables cannot have cyclic initializers, so type inference is fine.

Comment: Last sentence is inaccurate, see http://ideone.com/IQ4e80

Comment: @BenVoigt: I know.  https://twitter.com/Schabse/status/530389303340179458
But for all practical purposes, it is correct.

Comment: Shevdov's solution shouldn't compile, since it reads a variable which is not definitely assigned.  I went to some trouble to ensure that the variable would only be written to.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Shvedov's solution only works because the struct has no fields, so you aren't actually reading anything.  My original answer was `int x = x = 0;`